# Display on page ready

Tags: css

First of all sorry for my poor english. Do not hesitate to tell me if the problem I will try to describe is not clear...

I have a menu like this :

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Label 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>
      <a href="#">Label 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the ul.menu li, the child content is displayed with an accordion system.
My script is working well.

In the css, .sub-menu is displayed at "block" (in case of javascript is not activated in the browser).
In my script.js file, when the doc is ready, i launch a function which manage the menu.In this function,  I start by hidding the ul.sub-menu and then come the mechanisms of the menu .

My problem is, when the page is loading, I can firstly see the ul.sub-menu displayed as block, and very quickly, the "script.js" file does its work and hide those elements.
Each time the menu is displayed after a loading, it gives to the user an unpleasant effect as it looks like if the menu is flashing (everything opened, and then every sub-menu disappear).

How can I do to fix this issue ? Thanks in advance for your help...

NB - Everything is working regarding the functionalities, it's only a visual matter.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to start with

```
ul.sub-menu{
   display:none;
}
```

in your CSS.

And then to show that once the visitor has activated the link/hover, ec.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with you and I thought to it. But the problem is I wanted to keep the menu visible for people who don't have javascript activated on their browser.